# I need to create a small jquery plugin, but there is very strange issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Check here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brilliantcoder/u1a5svhx/9/)

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.my_alert = function(){
     var base = this;
       base.init = function() {
           base.on('click',function(e) {  base.onClick();   });
      }
       base.onClick = function(){
           alert(base.attr('data-id'));
       }
       base.init();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.myalert').my_alert();
});
```

When I click on any button it alerts the data-id attribute of the first button,

but I need it to instead show the data-id attr of the clicked button..

Comment: `base` in the plugin is a jQuery object holding multiple elements.

Comment: **↑↑↑↑** and `attr()` getter returns only first element attribute in set, so use `$(this)` not `base`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of `base` inside the click handler, where you should be using `this` instead as `base` is all the matching elements the plugin was attached to, not just the clicked element.

You should be doing it like this instead, dropping the `base` variable, and returning `this.each(...` to make it chainable

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.my_alert = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function(e) {
                alert( $(this).data('id') );
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Adeneo,  The main function  of my plugin is popup  check here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1a5svhx/12/)

I want if someone click save changes button then it put popup content into the hidden div from where the popup content was taken., but if some one click on cancel button or black overlay then it should put the same content in hidden div with out any changes.